# Sprind data jpa - How to handle selective fields posted by client to rest web service

Tags: spring, rest, spring-data-jpa

I am handling request through Spring data rest using jpa. I have a domain class say user, in this domain class there is lots of fields and mappings. When client want to update user data, they have to submit whole json body as per domain class. In want to handle it so that client can update user information by sending selective fields only. What is the best approach for doing this please suggest.
Sample JSON OBJECT mapped to User domain class:

```
{
"id": 1,
"oauthClientDetails": {
    "clientId": "8909241111",
    "resourceIds": null,
    "clientSecret": "secret",
    "scope": "read",
    "authorizedGrantTypes": "client_credentials",
    "webServerRedirectUri": null,
    "authorities": null,
    "accessTokenValidity": 18000,
    "refreshTokenValidity": null,
    "additionalInformation": "{}",
    "autoApprove": null
},
"deviceNo": "SMR01-4417-0002",
"deviceMasterType": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Single Phase",
    "description": "Single phase meter",
    "createdDate": "21-02-2018 10:11:03",
    "updatedDate": "24-02-2018 10:11:03",
    "statusMaster": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Active",
        "createdDate": "21-02-2018 10:11:03",
        "updatedDate": "21-02-2018 10:11:05",
        "status": "1"
    }
},
"societyName": "M G ROad",
"flatNo": "51",
"firstName": "rohit",
"lastName": "yadav",
"roleMaster": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Super user",
    "description": "This role provides all application permissions.",
    "createdDate": "23-02-2018 10:15:05",
    "updatedDate": "23-02-2018 10:15:05",
    "statusMaster": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "De-Active",
        "createdDate": "21-02-2018 10:11:03",
        "updatedDate": "21-02-2018 10:11:05",
        "status": "1"
    }
},
"statusMaster": {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Active",
    "createdDate": "21-02-2018 10:11:03",
    "updatedDate": "21-02-2018 10:11:05",
    "status": "1"
},
"email": null,
"countryMaster": {
    "id": 1,
    "countryCode": "BOL",
    "countryName": "Bolivia, Plurinational State of",
    "callingCode": "591",
    "createdDate": "21-02-2018 10:11:05",
    "updatedDate": "21-02-2018 10:11:05"
},
"otp": "1234",
"otpVerification": null,
"alternateMobile": "8800488281",
"createdDate": "28-02-2018 11:15:05",
"updatedDate": "02-03-2018 10:15:05",
"clientID": null
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You could partition your domain into sub domains, e.g.

`Device` contains (deviceNo) and `DeviceMaster` (deviceMasterType)
`Role`, `Status`, `Country` for roleMaster, statusMaster, countryMaster
with the root level elements such as email, updatedDate etc part of a base domain object such as `Client`.

your REST endpoints could then expose this domain structure to allow updating of partial information:

```
https://api.com/device
https://api.com/deviceMaster
https://api.com/role
https://api.com/status
https://api.com/country
https://api.com/client
```

and update the domain in parts. If a subdomain such as /device only needs the deviceNo updated, ignore the missing JSON fields when creating a domain object.

Answer (score 0):

While it's good idea to break into sub-domain classes as suggested by @codebrane.

But even your sub-domain classes can have selective fields.

So you should first define which are optional and mandatory fields. 
This first check should tell your clients what are the mandatory items they should send. 
You should use Bean validations to achieve this as supported by whichever vendor database you are using.

And, it is unlikely that all items in your JSON are dependent, for example, a user's address or device information cannot be created without first saving the user. 
If you put all of them in a single API then it will be hard for you to implement Single responsibility principle, rather not good as well.

In this scenario, you would correctly first save the user and then address, etc in a different API call.

Separate your dependent entities as separate domain objects which will help you in designing your REST APIs accordingly.

If you follow this approach then it helps you in giving the right responses to your clients as well. For e.g., an API which only takes address and fails for whatever reason will inform client that a single entity failed. If you had used Address, Contact, Device, etc all in one API then at server they can fail or pass independently and your API response will not be informative to the client.